# How to return the 2 elements before a match from an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just looking for most simple way to check if any field in object Array has value 0 and return previous two objects just before the object which contains the value 0.

```
for(var = 0; i <= result.length; i++)
    {

        //so in my case, it will return result[1] and result[2]
    }
```

How should I go about this?

**myresult data**

```
result =  [
    { A: 1, B: 2, C: 41, D: 124 },
    { A: 123, B: 221, C: 397, D: 81 },
    { A: 123, B: 412, C: 400, D: 454 },
    { A: 0, B: 412, C: 400, D: 454 }]
```

Comment: And if it's the first item - how will you return the "previous 2 elements" ?

Comment: There is no `int` in JavaScript.

Comment: @afasin sorry, there won't be any case in which first element includes 0 field

Comment: What if there is not object with `0` in it? Get the last 2?

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa and the second item as well ;)

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in a straightforward way: loop over the objects and for each one of them loop over its properties, once zero is found return the previous two items (by index):

```js
let result = [{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 41, D: 124}, { A: 123, B: 221, C: 397, D: 81}, { A: 123, B: 412, C: 123, D: 454}, { A: 0, B: 21, C: 53, D: 81}]

const getLastTwo = (objArray) => {
  for (let obj of objArray) {
    for (let prop in obj) {
      if (obj[prop] === 0) {
        const index = objArray.indexOf(obj)
        return [objArray[index-2], objArray[index-1]]
      }
    }
  }
  return [] // if we got here - no such element was found!
}

console.log(getLastTwo(result)) 
// [ { A: 123, B: 221, C: 397, D: 81 }, { A: 123, B: 412, C: 123, D: 454 } ]
```

Comment: from returned value, how should i get just first index of new array? i tried result[0] but get an error

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa `getLastTwo(result)[0]` or better yet: assign the the result to a new variable: `const newArray = getLastTwo(result)` and then `newArray[0]`

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa Sorry but it's not clear... it sound like you want to further process the result that was received here, please submit a new question with example of input, expected output and it's also important to post your code (which tried to achieve it and doesn't work) otherwise you'll get downvotes

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.. but `map` is one good ones in my opinion.

To get all the keys of object you can use `Object.keys` as below

```js
var result = [{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 41, D: 124}, { A: 123, B: 221, C: 397, D: 81}, { A: 123, B: 412, C: 123, D: 454}, { A: 0, B: 21, C: 53, D: 81}]

result.map((temp)=>{
    console.log(temp);
    Object.keys(temp).map((temp1)=>{console.log(temp1+":"+temp[temp1])})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's weirdly specific but this will do it, and won't throw errors if the second item in the array has a 0 value.

```
let objArr =  [
  { A: 1, B: 2, C: 41, D: 124}, 
  { A: 123, B: 221, C: 397, D: 81}, 
  { A: 123, B: 412, C: 123, D: 454}, 
  { A: 0, B: 21, C: 53, D: 81}]

let res = [];

objArr.forEach((obj, i) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if(obj[key] === 0){
      res.push(objArr[i - 1]);
      if(objArr[i - 2]){
        res.push(objArr[i - 2])
      }
    }
  })
})

console.log(res) //-> [{ A: 123, B: 221, C: 397, D: 81}, { A: 123, B: 412, C: 123, D: 454},]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) in combination with `Array#slice` like this:

```
function getTwo(arr) {
    let index = arr.findIndex(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k] === 0)); // get the index of the object whose some of his properties have the value 0
    return index < 0?                                                     // if the index is -1 (no such object is found)
               arr.slice(-2):                                             // then return the last two elements of the array
               arr.slice(Math.max(index - 2, 0), index);                  // otherwise return two object that occur right before the 0-object (if there is less than two then return as much as possible that's why we use Math.max in case index - 2 is negative)
}
```